# Use Union with while

Tags: mysql, sql, sql-server-2008, union, union-all

```
Go
Alter procedure SOW_proc
as
begin
    declare @i int
    set @i = 1
    declare @j int
    set @j = 1
    While(@i <= 84)
    Begin
        select ' ' as 'SOW_Id', ' ' as 'SOW_description', ' ' as 'CostCenter',
        ' ' as 'CostCenter_description', ' ' as 'CostCenter_type',  Profit,
        Revenue, Expenses, ' ' as 'Currency' 
        from Fact_table where SOW_Id is null

        union all
        Select 'Total' + '-' + SOW_table.SOW_Id, SOW_table.SOW_description, ' ', ' ', ' ',
        SOW_VW.Profit, SOW_VW.Revenue, SOW_VW.Expenses, SOW_VW.Currency
        from SOW_TABLE, SOW_VW
        where SOW_table.SOW_Id = SOW_VW.SOW_ID and SOW_TABLE.SOW_RowID = @i


        while(@j = @i)
        Begin
            select ' ' as 'SOW_Id', ' ' as 'SOW_description', ' ' as 'CostCenter',
            ' ' as 'CostCenter_description', ' ' as 'CostCenter_type',  Profit,  Revenue,
            Expenses, ' ' as 'Currency' 
            from Fact_table where SOW_Id is null
            union all
            Select SOW_TABLE.SOW_ID, SOW_TABLE.SOW_description, CostCenter_table.CostCenter,
            CostCenter_table.CostCenter_desc, CostCenter_table.Project_type,
            CostCenter_vw.Profit, CostCenter_vw.Revenue, CostCenter_vw.Expenses,
            CostCenter_VW.Currency 
            from SOW_TABLE, CostCenter_table, CostCenter_vw, Fact_table
            where SOW_TABLE.SOW_ID = FACT_TABLE.SOW_Id
            and FACT_TABLE.CostCenter_id = CostCenter_table.CostCenter_Id
            and CostCenter_table.CostCenter_id = CostCenter_vw.CostCenter_id
            and SOW_TABLE.SOW_RowID = @j 

            set @j = @j + 1;
        end
        Set @i = @i + 1
    end
end
```

When I run the above code, I got this result. I am unable to upload the pic due to insufficient points.
What I want is to remove all the headings between two rows as same heading is used. 
I am not able to use 'union all' as 'union all' can't be used with 'while'.
Please suggest some way to do that.

Comment: using WHILE in sql syntax usually indicates a wrong design and can 9½ times out of 10 be handled with normal join syntax. I'd advice you to redesign your query to not use WHILE before worrying about union

Comment: Post your table structre with data and required results ..

Comment: Why on earth would you want a procedure that returns 168 result sets? What does this mean - *"I am unable to upload the pic due to insufficient points"*? There is no limitation with using `UNION ALL` in conjuction with `WHILE`, the issue lies elsewhere. This seems like an [XY problem](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/66378/179361) - Perhaps a new question with clear details about the problem you are trying to solve, rather than the problems you are having with your attempted solution would attain a better response.

Comment: Also, for what it is worth the [JOIN syntax you are using is 20 years out of date](https://sqlblog.org/2009/10/08/bad-habits-to-kick-using-old-style-joins), and [using literals as column aliases is on the deprecation list](https://sqlblog.org/2012/01/23/bad-habits-to-kick-using-as-instead-of-for-column-aliases) (e.g. `SELECT expression AS 'alias'`)